# Joining a table of statements with And

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation

How could I algorithmically generate a statement such as

`Subscript[a, 1] ∈ Reals && Subscript[a, 2] ∈ Reals && Subscript[a, 3] ∈ Reals`

joining a table of statements stored in a table generated by

`Table[Subscript[a, j] ∈ Reals, {j,3}]`

with `And`s?

Comment: [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) is the way: `Apply[And, table]` or `And @@ table`. The idea is that `FullForm[table]` shows you that the [`Head`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) of your table is [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html); replacing this head with `And` does the trick.

Comment: also, it's not recommended to use Subscript, use [ ] instead. Or you can use `Element[Array[a,3], Reals]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Element`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html) has it's own shortcut.

> Element[x1|x2|…,dom]
>
> asserts that all the xi are elements of dom.

For a domain dom, {x1,x2,…}∈dom is equivalent to (x1|x2|…)∈dom.

So

```
Element[Array[a,3], Reals]
```

works.

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve my deeper problem. I tried ```$Assumptions=Element[Array[a,3], Reals]``` follows by ```Conjugate[a[1]]``` and Mathematica does not simplify the conjugate.

Comment: You need [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) but that's a separate issue.

Comment: `And @@ (Subscript[a, #] \[Element] Reals & /@ Range[3])`

Comment: @Roy - `$Assumptions` only affects functions that can use the option `Assumptions`.  `Conjugate` does not take options; however, `Simplify` can use the option `Assumptions`. Use `Conjugate[a[1]] // Simplify` or as pointed out by @Roman, use `ComplexExpand`. Note that while `ComplexExpand` does not take the option `Assumptions` and hence does not make use of `$Assumptions`, it will automatically assume that all variables are real unless told otherwise.

Comment: Here's my real issue at this point. I can not get mathematica to simplify `Conjugate[\[Epsilon] Subscript[u, 1][t]]` to `\[Epsilon] Conjugate[ Subscript[u, 1][t]]` using any of the above ideas. My `Assumptions` include that epsilon is real.

Comment: So you need to ask another question.   @Roy . BTW, this is called [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Tell `ComplexExpand` that `Subscript[u, 1][t]` is complex and that you want the result expressed in terms of `Conjugate`, i.e., `Conjugate[\[Epsilon] Subscript[u, 1][t]] // ComplexExpand[#, {Subscript[u, 1][t]}, TargetFunctions -> Conjugate] &`